# Bash exit option to cancel current (and all subsequent) scripts

Tags: bash, ubuntu

When I write my bash scripts, I try to organize them logically and in some instances I have a script (master) that calls others (slaves).  Within the master, if something fails, I simply use `exit` with an appropriate error message and everything stops. However, within the slave scripts, a failure using  `exit` will stop that slave from continuing, control is handed back to the master and the master merely carries on to the next part of it's execution.

Is there an option (or perhaps another command completely) that will stop the slave, as well as the master?  I wondered if perhaps when the master kicks off initially, I somehow grab the PID that it's running under and then in all subsequent tests, if I need a complete termination, then I use something like `kill PID#` (which I guess I could use in master as well as slaves).

Thinking about it in another light, would use an "exit 1" from the slaves and within the master, test `$?` after the call to each slave script and if it's not 0, stop?

Would either of these be a correct approach?

Comment: It is a good idea to have every script which you write, to return a non-negative exit code to indicate failures. There can be exceptions to this idea of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a slave script returns, the return is stored in $?. Just check what is being returned and if it is the error code then just exit from the master script.

Please let me know how I can help further.